How to prove inequality $2r^2(4+3r-6r^2-2r^4) <3$ for all $r \in [0,1]$
I am trying to prove the following inequality: For $r \in [0,1]$, to show that
$$ 2r^2(4+3r-6r^2-2r^4) <3 $$
I try evaluate the method of derivatives, but it is not working!
My method:
Let $f(r)=2r^2(4+3r−6r^2−2r^4)$, I calculate the first derivatives $$f′(r)=−24r^5−48r^3+18r^2+16r=2r(−12r^4−24r^2+9r+8).$$ I try solve equation $f′(r)=0$, and want to evaluate the value functions based on the variation table.
Could you please help me come up with an idea to prove this inequality? Thanks a lot!

Can you give a bit more detail on what you tried, e.g. what happened when you looked at the derivatives?

@ConMan Let $f(r) = 2r^2(4+3r-6r^2-2r^4)$, I calculate the first derivatives $f'(r) = −24r^5−48r^3+18r^2+16r = 2r(-12r^4-24r^2+9r+8)$. I try solve equation $f'(r)=0$, and want to evaluate the value functions based on the variation table. But it not working!

We have
\begin{align*}
 2r^2(4+3r-6r^2-2r^4) &\le 
 2r^2(4+3(1+r^2)/2-6r^2-2r^4) \tag{1}\\
 &= 2r^2(11/2 - 9 r^2/2 - 2r^4)\\
 &\le 2r^2(11/2 - 4 r^2 - 2r^4) \tag{2}\\
 &= 3 - (3 + r^2)(1 - 2r^2)^2 \\
 &\le 3
\end{align*}
where in (1) we use $r \le (1 + r^2)/2$,
and in (2) we use $-9 < -4$.
Clearly, the equality does not occur.
We are done.

I've used a brute force method, this one is very fine and elegant!

@River Li nice proof!

@DaiChiDO Perhaps the inequality is not strong.

We have that
$$2r^2(4+3r-6r^2-2r^4) <3 \iff f(r)=4 r^6 + 12 r^4 - 6 r^3 - 8 r^2 + 3>0$$
and by
$$f(r)=g(r)+h(r)=(4r^6-6r^3+2)+(12r^4-8r^2+1)>0$$
we have by completing the square

$g(r)=\left(2r^3-\frac32\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}<0$ for $r\in\left(\frac1{\sqrt[3]2},1\right)$ with minimum equal to $-\frac14$

$h(r)=3\left(2r^2-\frac23\right)^2-\frac{1}{3}<0$ for $r\in\left(\frac1{\sqrt 6},\frac1{\sqrt 2}\right)$ with minimum equal to $-\frac13$

$g'(r)=6r^2\left(4r^3-3\right)<0$ for $r\in\left(0,\sqrt[3]\frac34\right)$ with $\sqrt[3]\frac34>\frac1{\sqrt 2}$

$h'(r)=16r\left(3r^2-1\right)>0$ for $r>\frac1{\sqrt 3}$ with $\frac1{\sqrt 3}<\frac1{\sqrt[3]2}$



and since
$$g\left(\frac1{\sqrt 2}\right)=\frac52-\frac3{\sqrt 2}>\frac13$$
$$h\left(\frac1{\sqrt[3]2}\right)=3\sqrt[3] 4-4\sqrt[3] 2+1>\frac14$$
the result follows.

Another way by $r=\frac1x$ with $x\in(1,\infty)$
$$2r^2(4+3r-6r^2-2r^4) <3 \iff f(x)=3x^6-8x^4-6x^3+12x^2+4>0$$
and by
$$f(x)=u(x)+v(x)+z(x)=(2x^6-8x^4+8x^2)+ (x^6-6x^3+9)+(4x^2-5)>0$$
we have

$u(x)=2x^2(x^2-2)^2\ge 0$ with $g(x)=0 \iff  x=\sqrt 2$
$v(x)=(x^3-3)^2\ge 0$ with $h(x)=0 \iff x=\sqrt[3]3$
$z(x)=4x^2-5 \ge 0$ for $x\ge\frac{\sqrt 5}2$ with $z(x)=0 \iff x=\frac{\sqrt 5}2$

then it suffices to show that $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ are decreasing on $\left(1,\frac{\sqrt 5}2\right)$ and that on this interval
$$f(x) \ge u\left(\frac{\sqrt 5}2\right)+v\left(\frac{\sqrt 5}2\right)+z(1)=c>0$$

Let $f(r)=4r^6+12r^4-6r^3-8r^2+3$. Then $f'(r)=24r^5+48r^3-18r^2-16r.$
Due to Descartes' rule of signs and intermediate value theorem (IVT), there is only one root of $f'(r)=0$ in $(0,1)$ and by IVT that root is $a\in(0.6,0.7).$ We need to show that $f(a)>0$.
From $f'(a)=0$, we have $$a^4=-2a^3+\frac34 a+\frac23.$$
Hence, by reduction,  $$f(a)=-3a^3-\frac{40}3a^2+3a+\frac{17}3.$$
Let $g(x)=-3x^3-\frac{40}3x^2+3x+\frac{17}3
$. Then, it is not difficult to show that $g(x)>0$ on $(0,0.7).$
